# Not able to import CSS in LWC No MODULE named markup:

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, stylesheets

I have created a Lightning web component named commonStyleSheets and deleted html, JS file and kept only CSS file as shown in the below image.

[image]

Now if I import it by using  'c/commonStyleSheets' in any other lighting component's CSS

[image]

I am keep getting below error

[image]

I have deployed the commonSyleSheets component on my sandbox but still keep getting the above error, does anyone have any idea to solve this issue in a sandbox?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of my thread from the other day: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/314525/no-module-named-markup-when-importing-css-from-a-lwc

I am experiencing the same issue and I am uncertain as to why it's not working.

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, there seem to be a bug with Summer 20 release, when sharing a common CSS file with `import` function into another LWC component.

**Found another workaround** : always deploy the CSS component together with the child component.

So in your example, the `commonStyleSheets` component must contain only the CSS and meta xml file.

Let's say the child component is called `myComponent`, run the following command to deploy both css component and child component, then it will deploy successfully.

`sfdx force:source:deploy -p "force-app\main\default\lwc\commonStyleSheets", "force-app\main\default\lwc\myComponent"`

You need to have both components saved under API version 49.

Everytime you make changes in the child component `myComponent` file(s), then you will have to run the above command again to deploy both components together.

Answer (score 4):

Did some play-around and found there is apparently a bug in css [@import](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_lwc_css_share.htm) or in metadata deploy. Here is how you can reuse CSS:

1. Make sure the components are of API 49.0.
2. Create the reusable style sheet with js, meta and css files. Deploy.
   [image]
3. Now import this in the component css file you need. As you have `.js` file, it will not complain about the module. Deploy.

[image]

4. Now if you browse this component you will get error: (since the import is in CSS which is static in nature)
   [image]
5. So, you need to remove the `commonStyleSheets.js` file and deploy again.
   [image]

Now, if you browse the component again, it will render properly.

Congrats! now you are able to reuse CSS!

**Note: This bug is present as of Summer`20. This may be resolved in subsequent release patches or major release. As pointed by @Arthlete, you will need to repeat these steps every time you need to modify consumer components - its kind of annoying presently.**

Make sure you have default export in 2nd step:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class CommonStyleSheets extends LightningElement {}
```

Comment: I posted this as a solution as well the other day. However it only works until you need to modify the component where you imported the css. As soon as you try to deploy the consumer component you will get an error that the css component doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did exactly as mentioned in your answer created a commonStyleSheets component with JS, CSS and Meta file and then import it where it required and still deploy failed with same error nothing changed

Comment: @Arthlete. yes, you need the JS file every time you are deploying - kind of annoying, and again remove it after changes.

Comment: @gs650x Just check that you have export as you created js file later - this is definitely working - but the catch is it will be annoying every time you need to modify something in consumer component

Comment: @Arthlete added this point in answer

Comment: @salesforce-sas thank you, good job.